# How to construct a std::map from a range in VC6

Tags: c++, stl, visual-c++-6

Consider the code below that tries to construct a map from an iterator range:

```
#include <map>

template< typename C >
typename C::const_iterator cbegin( C const & c )
{
    return c.begin();
}

template< typename C >
typename C::const_iterator cend( C const & c )
{
    return c.end();
}

int main()
{
    typedef std::map<const int, int > Map;

    Map m1;
    Map m2( m1.begin(), m1.end() );
    Map m3( m1.begin(), m1.end(), std::less<const int>() );
    Map m4( cbegin( m1 ), cend( m1 ), std::less<const int>() );
}

// cl -nologo -EHsc vc6-map.cpp && vc6-map
// g++ -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++ -std=c++11 -o vc6-map vc6-map.cpp && vc6-map
```

g++ 4.8.1 succesfully compiles the code, whereas Visual C++ 6, SP6 (VC6) fails on constructing each of m2, m3 and m4.

VC6 gives the following errors:

```
prompt>cl -nologo -EHsc vc6-map.cpp && vc6-map
vc6-map.cpp
vc6-map.cpp(22) : error C2664: '__thiscall std::map<int const ,int,struct std::less<int const >,class std::allocator<int
> >::std::map<int const ,int,struct std::less<int const >,class std::allocator<int> >(const struct std::less<int const >
 &,const class std::allocator<int> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'class std::_Tree<int const ,struct std::pair<i
nt const ,int>,struct std::map<int const ,int,struct std::less<int const >,class std::allocator<int> >::_Kfn,struct std:
:less<int const >,class std::allocator<int> >::iterator' to 'const struct std::less<int const > &'
        Reason: cannot convert from 'class std::_Tree<int const ,struct std::pair<int const ,int>,struct std::map<int co
nst ,int,struct std::less<int const >,class std::allocator<int> >::_Kfn,struct std::less<int const >,class std::allocato
r<int> >::iterator' to 'const struct std::less<int const >'
        No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
vc6-map.cpp(23) : error C2664: '__thiscall std::map<int const ,int,struct std::less<int const >,class std::allocator<int
> >::std::map<int const ,int,struct std::less<int const >,class std::allocator<int> >(const struct std::pair<int const ,
int> *,const struct std::pair<int const ,int> *,const struct std::less<int const > &,const class std::allocator<int> &)'
 : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'class std::_Tree<int const ,struct std::pair<int const ,int>,struct std::map<int con
st ,int,struct std::less<int const >,class std::allocator<int> >::_Kfn,struct std::less<int const >,class std::allocator
<int> >::iterator' to 'const struct std::pair<int const ,int> *'
        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

vc6-map.cpp(24) : error C2664: '__thiscall std::map<int const ,int,struct std::less<int const >,class std::allocator<int
> >::std::map<int const ,int,struct std::less<int const >,class std::allocator<int> >(const struct std::pair<int const ,
int> *,const struct std::pair<int const ,int> *,const struct std::less<int const > &,const class std::allocator<int> &)'
 : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'class std::_Tree<int const ,struct std::pair<int const ,int>,struct std::map<int con
st ,int,struct std::less<int const >,class std::allocator<int> >::_Kfn,struct std::less<int const >,class std::allocator
<int> >::const_iterator' to 'const struct std::pair<int const ,int> *'
        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

For m2, VC6 seems unable to call the proper constructor. This is solved for construction of m3 and m4 by specifying the `std::less` comparator object. The only difference between the errors for construction of m3 and m4 is `iterator` versus `const_iterator`.

How can VC6 be tricked to do what is required?

Edit 14-Oct-2013: The VC6 map range constructor is defined as follows:

```
typedef const value_type *_It;
map(_It _F, _It _L, const _Pr& _Pred = _Pr(), const _A& _Al = _A()) {...}
```

This clarifies the error: the VC6 version requires a `std::pair<> const *` which is different from `std::map<>::const_iterator`.

Comment: VC6 is horribly, horribly bad, especially when it comes to STL. There really is no point in trying to fake it. Trying C++11 constructs such as `cbegin()` on a compiler that fails to implement half of C++98 is futile. Invest your time in upgrading to VS2012. Note that VC6 doesn't even target Vista and XP is EOL.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, I'm well aware of this and I _am_ going to try and migrate 'our' VC6 project. The question is if it can be done in a defensible amount of time, we'll have to see. Solving VC6 quirks starts to look like a hobby ;)  As an aside, you might be surprised that VC6 comes a long way at implementing the contemporary [Catch](http://martin-moene.blogspot.com/2012/12/catch-c-test-framework-vc6-port.html) test framework.

Answer (score 0):

Given the non-standard std::map range constructor in VC6, I see no real solution to construct a map from a range.

The function `add_to_map` below provides a workaround that works with VC6 and recent compilers.

```
template< typename M >
void add_to_map( M & m, typename M::const_iterator f, typename M::const_iterator t )
{
    for ( ; f != t; ++f )
    {
        m.insert( *f );
    }
}

int main()
{
    typedef std::map<const int, int > Map;

    Map m1;
    Map m5;
    add_to_map( m5, m1.begin(), m1.end() );
}
```

Please note that the following does not work in VC6 (template parameter 'U' is ambiguous):

```
template< typename T, typename U >
void add_to_map( std::map<const T,U> & m, ... )
```